# Flash Builder -- Is it possible to view verbose build logging?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, build, flash-builder, mxmlc

Is it possible to enable verbose build logging in Flash Builder?  Ideally, I want to be able to see the exact arguments that are being passed to the `mxmlc.exe` compiler.

**Context:**

I'm currently trying to automate our build process using GradleFx so we can move away from using Flash Builder and run our build on a CI server.  At present, I'm running into a few problems and my lack of knowledge about the flash/flex build process is impeding progress.

Being able to see what the FB project translates to would greatly aid me in being able to set up the new build scripts.

Comment: These have been very helpful when I first started building on the command line: lists of available compiler options for [mxmlc](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7a92.html) (application compiler) and [compc](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7a80.html) (component/library compiler)

Comment: One other thing: GradleFx uses convention over configuration, so if you just translate regular FB configs into GradleFx scripts, you should usually not have to provide any additional compiler arguments. Perhaps that's what's confusing you about the GradleFx sample scripts?

Comment: I understand the convention over configuration setup -- we're mostly using the default conventions and, where that is not possible, I've defined them in the top level gradle script so that they're propagated to subprojects.  GradleFx hasn't caused me many problems so far.  The main problem is just getting things set up correctly in terms of referencing dependent projects and whatnot -- e.g. getting the link types correct (rsl vs. external vs. library-path) plus including flex skins and whatnot.  I.e. it's less to do with the build system and more to do with my own ignorance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SourceMate plugin for Flash Builder is able to generate Ant build.xml from Project Settings

http://www.elementriver.com/sourcemate3/features/generate-ant-buildxml-project-settings